# fill column if another column list has element of all digit character

Tags: python, pandas

i have pandas dataframe in which i have to fill one new column based on column 'YYY'
In coumn 'YYY' i have following lists

```
YYY
1. ['BANK CHARGES', '00000321', 'NONE', 'None', '']
2. ['CHANGE CASH CHARGES', 'SELLING', '00000085', 'NONE', 'None', '']
```

I have to fill column 'NNN" if the list in column 'YYY' has 2nd element with all characters digits like in above if the case is true column 'NNN' should have value of 1st element of list and if not then 1 + 2(joined) element.

Comment: Please provide a proper sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select second values of lists by indexing by `str[1]`, check if all characters digits by [`Series.str.isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) and set new column in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df['YYY'].str[1].str.isdigit()
df['NNN'] = np.where(mask, df['YYY'].str[1], df['YYY'].str[0] + ' ' +df['YYY'].str[1])
print (df)
                                                 YYY  \
0             [BANK CHARGES, 00000321, NONE, None, ]   
1  [CHANGE CASH CHARGES, SELLING, 00000085, NONE,...   

                           NNN  
0                     00000321  
1  CHANGE CASH CHARGES SELLING
```

Alternative solution:

```
second = df['YYY'].str[1]
mask = second.str.isdigit()
df['NNN'] = second.where(mask, df['YYY'].str[0] + ' ' + second)
```

Comment: thanks this worked and give me idea where I was wrong.